# Autocomplete For Notepadqq

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, autocomplete, notepad++

I've Recently Installed Notepadqq On My Ubuntu 16.04 (Alternative To Notepad++)

I Really Liked It But I Just Need One Thing: Autocomplete Extension.
I Searched A Lot But Could Not Find Any Extension To Download So I Decided To Ask Here If Any One Can Help Me With That.

The Languages I Want To Work With Autocomplete Extension Are: Python, PHP, HTML, CSS, JS

Comment: https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq

Comment: check this but notepaddqq current version not supporting  auto completion

Comment: It the editor highlights the same words in text, the idea is that by hitting Ctrl+Enter the software could check previous digited words like the hint. Exemple: if above is declared myCrazyFunction, when typing myC and Ctrl+Enter a popup could suggest myCrazyFunction and autocomplete.